# how to do the webpart to list the items(doc,lib) available in current site in sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-2010

How to Create a webpart using client object Model and get the current site,loop through the List and Libraries get the documents which are uploaded by today & yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the object model is important, the SPSiteDataQuery class may fit the bill.  This allows you to query for the items of interest within a site collection.  A query like this will be faster and more robust than manually iterating through the lists and libraries via object model.  There are some good examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx).